# Avoid overriding suggestedmax when the tooltip callback function is called

Tags: chart.js

My angular application retrieves data from multiple APIs and displays it as a radar chart using chartjs 4 in a dashboard that monitors performance of multiple servers; each server is represented with its own radar chart. Lets assume the following datapoints are retrieved for a server:

- Active processes
- server response times
- DB response times

Suppose the value of the 'server response time' is very high, the chart tends to get larger and therefore distorting the other charts in the dashboard. So, I used 'suggestedmax' property to restrict the scale of the axis. Now, I would like the tooltip to show the actual value of 'server response time'. I'm using the callbacks function to show the values but the chart overrides the suggestedmax value and shows the full scale for 'server response time'

```
fetchResponseTimes (sid) {
this.apiCallService.getWsdl(sid).subscribe(
  wsdl => {
    this.apiCallService.getdialogResp(wsdl).subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log(result);
        const maxResponseTime = 200;
        const tempdata = [
          // Math.min( result['avgresptime'],maxResponseTime),
          result['avgresptime'],
          result['activewp'],
          result['dbresptime']
        ];
        this.data.labels.push('ResponseTime(Avg)','Active WP(%)','DB Responsetime(Avg)');
        this.data.datasets[0]['label'] = 'WM7';
        this.data.datasets[0]['data'] = tempdata;
        console.log(this.data);
        this.chart = new Chart('canvas',{
          type: 'radar',
          data: this.data,
          plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
          options : {
            elements: {
              line: {
                borderWidth: 3
              }
            },
            scales: {
             r: {
              suggestedMax: 200
             }
             
            },
            
            plugins: {
              tooltip : {
                callbacks: {
                  label: function (context) {
                    const labelIndex = context.dataIndex;
                    const datasetLabel = context.dataset.label || '';
                    const value = context.dataset.data[labelIndex];
                    return datasetLabel + ': ' + value;
                  }
                }

              }
            }
          }

        }) // end of chart data
      })
    })
   }
```

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do?
[image: Chart image with the responsetime]